# Save php output to PDF

Tags: php, css, pdf, printing

I have a script that opens a print dialogue to output some generated information that was styled with css. With this dialogue I can print to PDF. Is there a way to convert this output instantly to PDF?

I already tried some API web service like html2pdf, but these services generate only blank pages, because the output gets directly send to printing dialogue. Is there a way around this? (without styling my infos completely new with tcpdf / fpdf etc.)

Example: http://dev.prettynormal.de/index.php?task=productprint&pid=1480&_wpnonce=0f275205f2

Comment: are you want to down as PDF file?

Comment: Yes,i want it to be downloaded as pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use FPDF which is very easy to use;

```
require('fpdf.php');
 class PDF extends FPDF{
function header()//create header of the pdf
                {

                    $this->Image('Your Logo url', 10, 6, 90);
                    $this->Ln(30);
                    $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 15);
                    // Move to the right
                    $this->Cell(50);
                    // Title
                    // $this->Cell(90, 110, 'User Website Brief', 'C');
                    // Line break
                    $this->Ln(20);
                }
function footer()
                {

                    $this->SetY(-15);
                    // Arial italic 8
                    $this->SetFont('Arial', 'I', 8);
                    // Page number
                    $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Page ' . $this->PageNo() . '/{nb}', 0, 0, 'C');
                }

            }
$pdf = new pdf();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
            $title ='Your PDF Title';
            $pdf->SetTitle($title);
            $pdf->SetAuthor('Your Name');
            $pdf->AddPage();
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 14);
$pdf->cell(20, 10, $YourContent);
$pdf->Output('I',"FileName");//sends PDF output to the browser
```

You can download FPDF here
If it gives you problems please past your code so I can assist you.

Comment: Actually thats not what I want. The output is already styled with css and furthermore it is generated by a woocommerce extension.

Comment: Looks quiet promising. Is there a free alternative to this?

Comment: "We offer a free license for non-commercial use of Prince. This license adds a small logo to the first page of generated PDF files. For commercial use of Prince, you can purchase a full license, or use the DocRaptor service to convert HTML to PDF online." I think you can download it for free but it will add their logo.

Comment: This is commercial. The license costs several thousands of dollars

Comment: Just buy the thing man, its gonna help you for future use. I'm sure your clients are paying you well.

Comment: Haha, thanks no. I bet you're kidding...this feature is so small, I am not going top pay thousands of dollars for it.

Comment: These services do not work because of the dynamic content generation. There is always just a blank page. Besides, this is a paid plan too.

Comment: DocRaptor's has $15/mo plans, better than a few thousand.

Comment: I really like to have a onetime payment. As long it does not exceed 50-100$

Comment: I have bought another extension that uses mpdf. Does the job for 19$.

Comment: great glad you have finally found the solution.